# Listbox does not add item to its list. If I use selection.None

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox

I am using an array to populate my listbox. It worked fine but when I set the listbox.selection.none (I don't want items to be selected) then My listbox adds item to its first index but after that. It keeps the same value in an does not add new values. below is the code what i am using to add items to listbox from array.

```
Private array(10) As Decimal ' adds student score to array

dim index as integer = 0 '

Private Sub PopulateScoreList() ' method called when button is clicked
    If index < 10 Then 
        ' adds value to array at every button click event
        array(index) = Math.Round(value, 1)
    End If
    index += 1
    lbxTroopersScore.DataSource = Nothing
    lbxTroopersScore.DataSource = array 

end sub
```

Comment: Is the array large enough to hold your items? What's the size of it? Perhaps you should consider a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) instead?

Comment: yes, array is large enough. But I can't use List(ofT) does not follow coding standards for my project

Comment: as I said. array works if I set listbox.selection.one but does not work with none selection does not add new items to listbox. keeps the first entry in

Comment: Please show us some more code according to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We'll need to see variable and array declarations aswell.

Comment: Hmm, the code looks alright... I'll try it in a few minutes.

Comment: If you want un-select all items, you need to use `lst.SelectedIndex = -1`. And if you have `DataSource` set, I don't think you can add items. You need to use binding list or reassign array as new data source, which you do. I just don't see where you change array.

Comment: @T.S. : He modifies the array at the current index, which he increments right after that.

Comment: while debugging . I set the breakpoint at both datasource statements. the items were being added to the listbox and array at appropriate indexes. but on the form displayed the listbox does not show the updated values

Comment: Try to invalidate your control

Comment: @T.S. I tried. invalidate does not work. It is weird the listbox takes the score for first item (index 0) and displays. but after that the listbox does not change its value neither adds new

Comment: Seems like a bug.  Set the SelectionMode to One then back to None before you set the DataSource back to array.

Comment: @T.S. thanks man. it worked. there is probably some bug. setting selection to one. and after listbox get value. setting selection to none. makes it work

Comment: This is for @LarsTech :-)

Comment: This is definitely a bug, I tried it aswell (.NET 4.0). When I force the list box to invalidate itself all items disappear. -- Good workaround @LarsTech!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug.  Toggling the SelectionMode property fixes the problem:

```
lbxTroopersScore.DataSource = Nothing
lbxTroopersScore.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One
lbxTroopersScore.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None
lbxTroopersScore.DataSource = array
```